# How to shrink this particular if lines(messy) by using "?" operator

Tags: c#, operators

I am working on a project where I have to look into someone else's code and modify it.
However since many classmates in my class are quite new to program, many have such a messy organization. 
The code that I am assigned to improvise has a lot of flaws and messy redundant lines.
I am trying my best to clean them up, however due to my inexperience, I find it hard to clean them up. 
Lines such as

```
if (turnElapsed[1] == 2)
{
    turnElapsed[0] += 1;
    turnElapsed[1] = 0;
}
turnElapsed[1]++;
```

looks quite redundant to me.
I believe, and there must be a better way to write a simple version of it.
so I tried the code below but it seemed to not work properly.

```
turnElapsed[0] += (turnElapsed[1]++ == 2) ? 1 ; 0 ;
turnElapsed[1] = (turnElapsed[1] == 2 ) ? 0; turnElapsed[1];
```

Comment: Whoa. You think that the second code block is *easier* to read and understand at a glance than the first one?

Comment: The first line should be ... += (turnElapsed[1] == 2) ? ... No ++ afterwards

Comment: Both codes are written by me it originally used two separated if statements but then I shrinked it to one but still I would like to shrink it a bit more. The second code seemed better to me thought do not know why it is not working

Comment: @David.Chu.ca but I want to add 1 to turnElapsed[1]

Comment: I can't add and condition at the same time?

Comment: What's the point of trying so hard to shrink it up? Let the compiler handle optimizing the code. I promise it doesn't care one whit if it takes 1 line or 20. The only thing you need to worry about as the programmer is clarity and readability. That was the point of my comment.

Comment: The first line should be ... += (turnElapsed[1] == 2) ? 1: 0 ... No ++ afterwards. The next line is something like ...? 1 : .... By the way, the syntax should be ? A : B; Yours is ? A ; B;

Comment: @user1143720 the fact that you are having difficulty getting the dense code to work properly is not evidence of your inexperience; it is evidence of the difficulty of writing and maintaining dense statements.  The evidence of inexperience, on the other hand, is the fact that you are trying to create such dense code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the feedback. I appreciate it and I am greatful to learn the fact clearity over density.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you are using `;` as separator instead of `:` which is a syntax error. Secondly, you're incrementing `turnElapsed[1]` on the first line, which means that when it reaches the  second line it will no longer equal 2 - that's different to the original logic. This is why your version does not work properly.

However, if you did fix those errors I don't think your code would be easier to read. The original is more readable, because it expresses the intention more clearly. You can read that and verbalise it as "if turnElapsed[1] is 2 then ...". Your alternative takes fewer lines, but is more "cryptic". Another advantage of the original code is that you can put a breakpoint inside the braces if you wanted to break when the if condition was true - you cannot do that with the ternary operator (?).

Comment: It's in the loop so the second time it should be 2 and then [0] adds one to itself and [1] becomes zero again

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that it is not readable and comprehensible. That is why you don't see your bug.
The bug is that you don't increment in the second version. Try this

```
turnElapsed[0] += (turnElapsed[1]++ == 2) ? 1 : 0 ;
turnElapsed[1] = ((turnElapsed[1] == 2 ) ? 0; turnElapsed[1]) + 1;
```

Comment: That just incremented [1] by 2 in my compiler :3

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you just keeping a binary number in turnedElapsed, with the most significant bit in turnElapsed[0]? A much better version of the code would be:

```
long turnElapsed;

...

turnElapsed++;
```

Or, if you really don't want to start messing with bits:

```
turnElapsed[0] += turnElapsed[1]
turnElapsed[1] = (1 + turnElapsed[1]) % 2
```

EDIT: Apparantly turnElapsed[1] is 0 or 1, and turnElapsed[0] is incremented every time turnElapsed changes from 1 to 0. So you have the following:

```
long number;

...

number++;
turnElapsed[0] = number/2;
turnElapsed[1] = number%2;
```

No need for ifs, ?:'s or anything else. In fact, you don't even need the array.